# Flutter state management, can't refresh in realtime

Tags: flutter, state, state-management

I have 2 widgets, and I want to show the second one after a user clicked the first one but I can't refresh my app when the user clicked the first one, if I manually refresh my page other widget appears.

**Method**

```
    Widget buildCategoriesList(List<Container> _list, bool chosenCategory) {
        if (!chosenCategory)
          return CategoriesList(
            list: _list,
          );
        else {
          print(chosenCategory);
          setState(() {});
// Example Second widget
          return Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

**Widget**

```
class CategoriesList extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoriesList({
    Key key,
    @required List<Container> list,
  })  : _list = list,
        super(key: key);

  final List<Container> _list;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: _list.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 9),
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => chosenCategory = true, child: _list[index])));
  }
}
```

**Body**

```
Expanded(
            flex: 4,
           child: buildCategoriesList(_list, chosenCategory),
         ),
```

Comment: `buildCategoriesList` is not called anywhere, what is it used for? where is "clicking" code? could you post working minimal example?

Comment: used in body, Expanded widget

Comment: in my CategoriesList, i wrapped child  GestureDetector, which has onTap method, that's where im changing my boolean to true, as i expect it has to change when i click any of my list Builder elements because i changed the boolean but nothing happens in realtime.

Comment: *"where im changing my boolean to true, as i expect it has to change when i click"* - because you set `chosenCategory = true` without changing state

Comment: And how can i change state in my custom widget ? searched for this problem before but couldn't find something useful

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#managing-state

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: issue fixed with this approach.